# Dynamic binding of params array MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm building a search feature for my website where the user can search using 3 parameters. The user can choose to enter all 3 to filter the table or none at all and receive the whole table. I figured out how to dynamically build the query depending on what the user inputs but I'm having trouble calling `bind_params()` with the right number of arguments and the right order.

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT position, rank, fullname, phonenumber, email, division 
FROM `table` WHERE 1=1 ";


if(!empty($_POST['fname'])){
   $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
   $sql .= " AND `fullname` LIKE '%?%'";
}


if($_POST['div'] !== "All"){
   $division = $_POST['div'];
   $sql .= " AND `division` LIKE '%?%'";
}


if(!empty($_POST['pos'])){
   $position = $_POST['pos'];
   $sql .= " AND `position` LIKE '%?%'";
}


$stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmnt -> bind_param('sss', $firstname, $division, $position); 
$stmnt -> bind_result($position, $rank, $fullname, $phonenumber, $email,$division);
$stmnt -> execute();
```

I always get this error: `Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement` I understand why I'm getting it but I tried multiple things but nothing worked out. Any hints or links to documentation would be useful. Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting this is easier to do with PDO since it has named placeholders and you can just pass in an `array()` structure to `execute()`.

Comment: @tadman can you point me to an example, if you don't mind?

Comment: Note: execute, then bind the result. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php which is probably the major fault here while making sure that "all" the conditions are met and that all POST arrays contain values. If one of those should fail, so would your query.

Comment: There's a lot of places to go to learn about PDO, but [here's one](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) that goes through the basics. Adding things to an associative array is easy, and later you can `execute()` with those values. Doing this with `mysqli` requires low-level PHP hacking to pass in arbitrary arguments, it's a giant mess.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for the link. However, that isn't the issue here I'm making sure all the POST arrays contain values but I'm having trouble supplying the right arguments to `bind_params`. I'm looking at PDO now like @tadman suggested.

Comment: @tadman thank you, I'll take a look now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your data and parameters as an array:

```
$data = array();
$format = array();

if(!empty($_POST['fname'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
    $sql .= " AND `fullname` LIKE '%?%'";
    $format[] = 's';
    $data[] = $firstname;
}
```

Then pass them by reference and bind with call_user_func_array

```
if(!empty($format) && !empty($data)):

            $format = implode( '', $format );
            $format = str_replace( '%', '', $format );

            array_unshift( $data, $format );
            call_user_func_array( array( $stmnt , 'bind_param' ), (referenceValues( $data ) );

        endif;
```

The pass by reference function:

```
public function referenceValues($array)
    {
        $refs = array();

        foreach ($array as $key => $value):

            $refs[$key] = &$array[$key];

        endforeach;

        return $refs; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I switched to PDO but I will accept your answer for future visitors.